# Ember.js and selecting multiple models for deleting

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In ember.js documentation i've found next:

> controllers allow you to decorate your models with display logic. In general, your models will have properties that are saved to the server, while controllers will have properties that your app does not need to save to the server.

I'm trying to add "selecting" functionality to my application.

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JWf7X/

Seems that filter property is filtering by model, not by controller (because the console.log is empty).

```
this.filterProperty('isSelected', true); //managing models
```

How can i write removeSelected action correctly?

Is the correct way to storing "isSelected" in controller? I think adding isSelected for model is not the right way, because this property will not load from server via REST API and will not be save to it.

**application.js:**

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();



App.Test = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
});


App.Test.FIXTURES = [
 {
   id: 1,
   title: 'Learn Ember.js',
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   title: '...',
 },
 {
   id: 3,
   title: 'Profit!',
 }
];

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.get('store').find('test');
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
      removeSelected: function () {
        var selected = this.filterProperty('isSelected', true);
        console.log(selected);
      }
  },

});

App.TestController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isSelected: false,
});
```

**index.html:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <button {{action "removeSelected"}}>remove selected</button>
    <ul>
      {{#each itemController="test"}}
        <li>
          {{input type="checkbox" checked=isSelected}}
          <label>{{title}}</label>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking the source, using the `itemController`, in the each view helper. Will create a new array controller instead of use your `IndexController`. So `isSelected` will not be present inside of `IndexController`.

If you set the `itemController` into `App.IndexController` you will get this working:

**indexController:**

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: "test",
  actions: {
      removeSelected: function () {
        var selected = this.filterProperty('isSelected', true);
        console.log(selected);
      }
  }
});
```

**index.html:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <button {{action "removeSelected"}}>remove selected</button>
    <ul>
      {{#each}}
        <li>
          {{input type="checkbox" checked=isSelected}}
          <label>{{title}}</label>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

This is a updated fiddle with this working http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/BKUyk/

Comment: Thnx for help. I mistakenly thought that setting itemController in each helper will set it for IndexController.

Comment: You are welcome. Just an update in my answer, `each itemController="test"` isn't needed just `each`. The fiddle is right.